# HibernateTemplate , bulkUpdate and flush mode

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, transactions

We are using hibernateTemplate for our dao's within my current project. I have a situation where I want to have a transaction that rolls back if either operation within the transaction fails (not rocket science, right?).. so basically, here is the method:

```
    // Reserve a deal and add the 'pending order' all in one transaction
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private MyUserOrder reserveQuantity(MyUserOrder userOrder, Date updatedOn) throws MyAPIException{

    userOrder.setOrderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING);
    int orderReserved = orderDao.reserveQuantity(userOrder);

    //for some reason hibernate is flushing on the above line???

    if (dealsReserved < 1)
            throw new MyAPIException(ExceptionCode.INSUFFICIENT_QUANTITY);

    userOrder = userOrderDao.save(userOrder);

    //hibernate flushes again!

    return userOrder;
}
```

So, basically we reserve X orders from the databases order availability table... and then save the pending order to the database. I'd like both statements to execute in the same transaction, so if one fails they both roll back. Unfortunately, it looks like the statement for .reserveQuantity is being committed immediately, even though the whole method should run within it's own transaction.

Here is the log..

```
    13:09:28.007 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13291529680
13:09:28.008 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Registering Spring transaction synchronization for new Hibernate Session
13:09:28.009 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate - Found thread-bound Session for HibernateTemplate
13:09:28.011 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
13:09:28.011 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
13:09:28.012 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:db2://172.26.10.144:60000/devdb]
13:09:28.189 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update deal set remaining_quantity=remaining_quantity-?, updated_on=?, updated_by=? where id=? and remaining_quantity>=?
13:09:28.242 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
13:09:28.243 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
13:09:28.244 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate - Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after HibernateTemplate
13:09:28.245 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
13:09:28.246 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Registering Hibernate Session for deferred close
13:09:30.524 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
13:09:30.525 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13291529705
13:09:30.534 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
13:09:30.537 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
13:09:30.540 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
13:09:30.543 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
13:09:30.549 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress
13:09:30.551 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.s.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate - Eagerly flushing Hibernate session
13:09:30.552 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
13:09:30.554 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
13:09:30.556 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.Collections - Collection found: [<redacted>.UserOrder.dealOrderSet#<delayed:8>], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
13:09:30.558 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 5 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 5 objects
13:09:30.559 [5253145@qtp-25442933-1] DEBUG o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
```

As you can see, two flush operations occurred.. one about halfway through the log (when I reserve) and another at the end when I try to save the order bean. Here is my data sources config.

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dealsdbDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="<redacted>.common"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate-show-sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" name="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />               
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Also upon investigation, it looks like my flushmode is AUTO in hibernateTemplate.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check , if you have declared @Transactional in the orderDao class.
I suppose that could be the cause.

best practice is to have @Transactional at the service layer and not to have any at the DAO layer.

Comment: No @Transactional is only on the